# Open a xib file change the content of the file

Tags: xcode

I am using XCode 6.1 to work on an ios App. I am using git as source control.
I want to know why whenever I open a xib file in XCode, it changes the content of xib file and git sees that file has been modified.

I search stackoverflow and see it was an issue with old xcode. 
Is it still a issue with xcode 6.1? is there a way to work around this?

Comment: It does still happen occasionally. Just touching the file accidentally in Xcode can trigger this. I don't know what you mean by "work around"... Just live with it. All that's changing is a version string.